# How to tell RStudio to use TinyTex instead of MiKTeX?

Tags: r, rstudio, miktex, tinytex

I want to use LaTeX in RStudio with `Sweave`. However, I run into problems with using MiKTeX (see [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814278/set-path-to-miktex-for-pdflatex-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)). As I couldn't solve these issues I want use `TinyTeX` now. I installed `TinyTeX` in RStudio:

```
install.packages('tinytex')
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

However, I couldn't figure out where to tell RStudio that it should use `TinyTeX` instead of MiKTeX when I want to compile a PDF based on a `Rnw` file. I checked the global options, but couldn't find what I was looking for. I am aware that it is recommended to unistall MiKTeX if using TinyTeX, but I want to keep both on my computer.

There should be a way if I read the conclusion of this discussion correctly: [Ref](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2788).

Note: RStudio version: 1.4.1717.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do this:

```
Tools -> Global Options -> Sweave -> LaTeX Editing and Compilation -> Use tinytex when compiling .tex files.
```

Comment: Ah, why didn't I see that. Thanks a lot.