# Errors compiling Rnw beamer presentation

Tags: latex, sweave, beamer, rnw

I have a collection of old lectures, written as `.Rnw` files using LaTeX beamer for presentations.
They no longer compile, and I am mystified why.

Here is a minimal example, `test-beamer.Rnw` just trying to produce a title slide

```
\documentclass[10pt,table,handout]{beamer} 

%\input{inputs/beamer-setup}
%\input{inputs/defs}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\title[6136: Overview]{Categorical Data Analysis: Course Overview}
\author{Michael Friendly}
\institute{Psych 6136}
% insert titlegraphic
\titlegraphic{
 \rule[-4pt]{0.5pt}{4pt}\hrulefill\rule[-4pt]{0.5pt}{4pt}  \\
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth,clip]{fig/bertifier} \\
  \rule{0.5pt}{4pt}\hrulefill\rule{0.5pt}{4pt} \\
}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Using the "Compile PDF" button, I get an uninformative message:

```
Writing to file test-beamer.tex
Processing code chunks with options ...

You can now run (pdf)latex on 'test-beamer.tex'
Running pdflatex.exe on test-beamer.tex...failed
Error running C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe (exit code 3)
```

I opened the `test-beamer.tex` fil in TeXstudio and tried to compile.  The `.log` file ends with something about `geometry.sty` and an error from `ifvtex.sty`,
but I cannot tell how or where `ifvtex.sty` is invoked.  Can anyone help?

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.8.28) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.10.13)  13 OCT 2022 16:06
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./test-beamer.tex
(test-beamer.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-09-28>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/beamer\beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2022/09/13 v3.68 A class for typesetting presentations
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasemodes.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
....
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbaseoptions.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
))
\beamer@paperwidth=\skip48
\beamer@paperheight=\skip49

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.20 \IFTEX@let
               {vtexdvi}{false}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

**Follow-up**:
I downloaded the `iftex` package from the CTAN archive, installed this in my `localtexmf/` directory and refreshed the database.

`kpsewhich` now finds both `iftex.sty` and `ifvtex.sty`

```
$ kpsewhich iftex.sty
C:/Dropbox/localtexmf/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty

friendly@UIT-HHP-9L7JNK3 MINGW64 /c/R/projects/heplots (master)
$ kpsewhich ifvtex.sty
C:/Dropbox/localtexmf/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
```

Yet, when I try to compile the `.tex` file generated, I still get an error:

```
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty
(C:/Dropbox/localtexmf\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
l.20 \IFTEX@let
               {vtexdvi}{false}
?
```

RStudio inserts the line below in the .tex file.  Could this be the source of my grief?

```
\usepackage{Sweave}
```

Comment: please check if the iftex package is installed, see also https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/137#issuecomment-549800150

Comment: Thanks for this helpful link. Yes, the MikTeX 2.9 package manager shows I have `iftex.sty`, dated 2022-02-07 installed by Admin.  I am getting a similar error on another machine (Win 10), and it occurs just after `geometry.sty` is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

No one answered, so here is what I've done that works now.

- Copied `iftex.sty` and `ifvtex.sty` to the local directory of my source `.Rnw` files.  No idea why this was necessary, but perhaps this item about MikTeX paths is relevant: [Set path to miktex for pdflatex in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814278/set-path-to-miktex-for-pdflatex-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- Still had problems with MikTeX, so I switched to `tinytex` via R Stidio `Tools -> Global options -> Sweave -> Use tinytex when compiling .tex`